# How do I count visits of page in Django? (through redirecting)

Tags: python, django, redirect, view, count

I've read through several other questions, yet what I was looking for wasn't there.

I want to count how many times the user has gone through the **ToPost/to_post.html** section.

*Delayed redirecting works*, but *incrementing number of visits doesn't*: `post.visit_num += 1`

I have a **view** whose template redirects after a second:

```
def ToPost(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.visit_num += 1
    args = {'post': post}
    return render(request, 'posts/to_post.html', args)
```

The pk is in the URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/to-post/$', views.ToPost, name='to_post'),
```

Template **to_post.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url={% url 'home_space:view_post' pk=post.pk %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>
        To post {{ post.pk }}...
    </h2>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The model of **Post**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Title')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Description')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    visit_num = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: You didn't save the post after incrementing the visit count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to save the `post` instance after incrementing and also use `F` object to avoid race condition. Also don't capitalize the function name use snake_case instead, more about `F` objects here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

```
from django.db.models import F    

def to_post(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.visit_num = F('visit_num') + 1
    post.save()
    args = {'post': post}
    return render(request, 'posts/to_post.html', args)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to save the changes to the post:

```
post.save()
```